# How to assign drive links with loop in colab

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary, google-colaboratory

I want to assign these links in a loop. But I don't know what to use.

I tried dictionary but i couldn't do it

```
from google.colab import drive

drive.mount('/content/drive')

video_1 = "/content/drive/MyDrive/outputs_1"
video_2 = "/content/drive/MyDrive/outputs_2"
video_3 = "/content/drive/MyDrive/outputs_3"
video_4 = "/content/drive/MyDrive/outputs_4"
video_5 = "/content/drive/MyDrive/outputs_5"
video_6 = "/content/drive/MyDrive/outputs_6"
video_7 = "/content/drive/MyDrive/outputs_7"
video_8 = "/content/drive/MyDrive/outputs_8"
video_9 = "/content/drive/MyDrive/outputs_9"
video_10 = "/content/drive/MyDrive/outputs_10"
video_11 = "/content/drive/MyDrive/outputs_11"
video_12 = "/content/drive/MyDrive/outputs_12"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a list works for you, you could do this:

```
from google.colab import drive

drive.mount('/content/drive')

video_list = ["/content/drive/MyDrive/outputs_" + str(i) for i in range(1, 13)]
```

If you need help regarding list comprehension:
[Check this out!](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists_comprehension.asp)